# get the event of a component, get the value and push to Array

Tags: custom, lightning-events

I replaced one of my input field for a custom lookup component. I can get the value of it and add it to a variable. The problem I have is I need to push it to an Array and I cannot get the name of the component as this is not a property like the Input-Field. See below
HTML:

```
<td scope="col">
    <!--COMPONENT-->
    <c-lwc-lookup object-api-name="product2" icon-name="standard:product" onrecordselection={changeHandler}> </c-lwc-lookup>
</td>
<td scope="col">
    <!--InputField-->
    <lightning-input value={field.Description__c} data-index={index} access-key={index} type='text' name="fieldDescription" onchange={changeHandler}>
    </lightning-input>
</td>
```

My component is a lookup on the object Product2. and once I select the product, I am calling the changeHandler function where I need to get the accesskey and add the value to my Array. Unfortunately, it is not working like the Input Field... Here is my changeHandler

```
changeHandler(event){
        var index = event.target.dataset.index;
    
        //This is the component part that is not working
        //event.target.name is not working because the component doesn't have that attribute 
        if(event.target.name==='product2'){
            //event.target.accessKey is not working neither but I can add it to the component but still not working
            this.contentArray[event.target.accessKey].Name = event.detail.selectedValue;
        }
        //This is the Input-Field and works as a charm.
        else if(event.target.name==='fieldDescription'){
            this.contentArray[event.target.accessKey].Description = event.target.value;
        }        
    }
```

If I had only one line it will work by just using a variable but I have multiple lines...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give it a name, so it wouldn't have a name. Conceptually, you could give it a name:

```
<c-lwc-lookup name="product2" ...
```

You'd probably have to modify c-lwc-lookup to have an @api attribute to make this work.

You can choose to not modify the component, and still access its' public property `object-api-name` if you wanted to:

```
if(event.target.objectApiName === 'product2') {
```

Or, you could add a data attribute, as in:

```
<c-lwc-lookup data-name='product2' ...
```

Then:

```
if(event.target.dataset.name === 'product2') {
```

Other options are possible as well. You just need to coordinate how you want it to work.

Comment: Yes, I tried your first example yesterday before posting here and had no luck as I guess name= is not supported with my component and probably need to add it like you are saying to the @api attribute, I am too rookie to think about that but I'll remember for next time ;) I used data-name instead and it works like a charm! Where can I find a list of all attributes? I search, I Google it and found some peaces but not that one... Your help is always appreciated! ;)

Comment: @Eric All attributes for what, exactly? Your component has whatever attributes you define with `@api`. For standard components, check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/).

Comment: Example: data-name=, object-api-name=, data-index=, access-key=, value=. I guess some of them are default by component like name= for input Fields and some can be custom when you create your component. Is data-name= custom? Sorry for my rookie question

Comment: @Eric any attribute that is `@api` can be used, such as `name` or `access-key`, these vary by component (again, check the docs). The `data-*` attributes are used to attach private use data from your own component to keep track of which element is which (like which element in an iterator was referenced). The component never needs to declare `@api` variables for `data-*` attributes.